# Why doesn't my chai rejectedWith assertion work?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm using Coffeescript, Mocha, and chai, and I have the following code:

```
class Herp extends Error
message = "derpy!"

class Foo
    @bar: ->
        new Promise(() =>
            throw Herp(message)
        )

describe 'Berp', ->
    it 'should herp a derp', ->
        Foo.bar().should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(Herp(message))
```

I do not understand why, when I run this test, it tells me:

```
AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected with [Error: derpy!] but it was rejected with [Error: derpy!]
```

Cause that message looks an awful lot like it's saying that it expected it to be rejected with the exact thing it was rejected with. What am I doing wrong here?

```
❯ grep chai package.json         
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.3.0",

❯ node --version
v6.4.0

❯ npm --version 
3.10.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chai-as-promised's `rejectedWith()` assertion somehow resembles chai's `throw()`; and `throw()` does just strict `===` comparison. Of course your errors are two completely different object and so are not strict equal.

In such situation we use `deep` comparisons. but chai does not support `deep` equality on throws so we cannot simply say something like:

```
 Foo.bar().should.eventually.be.deep.rejectedWith(Herp(message));
```

Of course `rejected` matcher is chainable so something like the following should work:

```
Foo.bar().should.eventually.be.rejected.and.deep.equal(Herp(message));
```

Also see: [#113](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/113) and [#1065](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/1065) for other possible solutions and issue tracking.